# calculate cost of route segments

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm

table with routes:

```
route_id | points 
       1 | [A,B] 
       2 | [L,G,C,F,E]
```

table with the cost of route segments:

```
route_id | point A | pointB | cost
       1 | A       | B      |   10
       2 | L       | G      |   10
       2 | G       | C      |   20
       2 | C       | F      |   15
       2 | F       | E      |   13
```

it is necessary to calculate the cost between the points 'G' and 'E' in route_id=2

Comment: You want this only using sql ?, we can fetch this data in any other backend language data structure and solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result using **"Recursive With Clause".**

Table:

```
create table test(
route_id int, 
pointA char,
 pointB char, 
 cost int
);
```

Values:

```
insert into test values(1 ,'A','B',10),
(2 ,'L','G',10),
(2 ,'G','C',20),
(2 ,'C','F',15),
(2 ,'F','E',13)
```

Recursive Query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE routecost AS (
SELECT pointA, pointB ,cost  /* non recursive part */ 
FROM test                   
WHERE pointA = 'G'
  and route_id = 2 
UNION ALL
SELECT b.pointA, a.pointB, a.cost + b.cost   /* recursive part */               
FROM test a                
JOIN routecost b ON(a.pointA = b.pointB)    
  where a.route_id = 2
)
SELECT * FROM routecost
where pointB = 'E'
```

Explanation:

1. First filter the query with pointA and route_id in non recursive
   part.
2. Then in recursive part join it as shown in query and add cost
3. I am fetching b.pointA (in non recursive part) every time because we
       need start point.
4. Then finally I am filtering it to pointB value to get required
   result.

[Reference: Recursive with clause](http://technobytz.com/recursive-query-evaluation-postgresql.html)